# How to delete two elements in a page DOM with PHP

Tags: php, dom, element

I have to delete a element in the DOM of current webpage, via PHP. The following code would seem to work, but I can't load the page the way I did, because the code would run every time in an infinite loop all over again. Also removing something by loading the page is inefficient and would slow down the page loading time. How can I do? Thanks for help!

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("https://www.example.com/product1/");

$selector = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($selector->query('//div[contains(attribute::class, "my-class1")]') as $e ) {
    $e->parentNode->removeChild($e);
}

$dom->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: "because the code would run every time in an infinite loop all over again" <- what do you mean? Side note, you can do `//div[@class='my-class1']`.

Comment: you will need to use `output buffering` to delete items from the `current page` - loading the buffer into a `DOMDocument` instance, modifying the DOM and then flushing the buffer

Comment: @Jeto `//div[@class='my-class1']` works well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete content from the `current page` using PHP you must process the `output buffer` before it is rendered using `ob_start` with the callback function doing the modifications on the DOM.

A very basic example below will remove all elements with `my-class1` class

```
<?php
    function callback($buffer){
        $dom=new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML( $buffer );
        $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
        $col=$xp->query( '//div[ contains( @class, "my-class1" ) ]' );
        foreach( $col as $node )$node->parentNode->removeChild( $node );
        return $dom->saveHTML();
    }
    ob_start('callback');
    ob_implicit_flush();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>DOM Manipulation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='my-class1'>#1</div>
        <div class='my-class1'>#2</div>
        <div class='my-class1'>#3</div>

        <div class='my-class2'>#4</div>
        <div class='my-class2'>#5</div>
        <div class='my-class2'>#6</div>
    </body>
</html>
```